# How do I find DropWizard request start time?

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

How do I find the time that a request was received, from inside the resource?  I'm not finding any information about this in either DropWizard docs nor Jersey docs.

For my needs, I would prefer the time that the request was first received (before any request processing), but if that's not available, do I have any options than simply capturing the time in the resource itself?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now()` will give you the current date and time in your application.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I did, but I had hoped to get info about when dropwizard got the request.

Comment: if this is across the board for everything and you only want to log that, i thin i would add a reqeust filter that is executed on every resource method first logging out the details of that. the log will have your timestamp